# typedef Vector sent into function to read from file into a vector

Tags: function, c++11, vector, typedef

the program runs perfectly with arrays but i have to convert every array into unsized vector and once i changed the iarray for a vector in the typedef the program compiles but it times out saying the time it ran for and a value that was returned

```js
//Author: Miguel Acosta
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

//universal variables
const int size=99;
const int col=3;
int studentsize=0;
//user friendly setup
using namespace std;
using std::setw; 
//typedef for arrays
typedef vector<int unsigned> iarray; //ID
typedef short table[size][col]; //quiz scores
typedef float farray[col]; // average
typedef short sarray[col]; //lowest 
typedef float starray[size]; //student average

//functions declaration
void printall(iarray, table, farray, starray, sarray, sarray, int);
void findqavg(table, farray);
void findlow (table, sarray);
void findhigh(table, sarray);
void findstudavg(table, starray );
void getdata(iarray studentid, table score, ifstream &infile);
int main()
{  
    ifstream infile("pr2data.txt");
     
     //variable declaration and initialization
     iarray studentid;
     table score;
     farray average={0};
     starray studavg={0};
     sarray lowest={100};
     sarray highest={0};
     
     //error if file did not open
     if(!infile.is_open()){
      
  cout << "inInfo.txt could not be accessed!" << endl;

    }
 
     else if(infile.is_open()){
   
          

        getdata(studentid, score, infile);
     infile.close();
     
    }
     
    //invoking functions
    findqavg(score, average);
    findlow(score, lowest);
    findhigh(score, highest);
    findstudavg(score, studavg);
    
   printall(studentid, score, average, 
    studavg, highest, lowest, studentsize);
   

cin.get();
cin.ignore();

return 0;
}//end of main


//read data from file--------------------
void getdata(iarray studentid, table score, ifstream &infile)
{
    
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        
        infile>>studentid[i];
        
        if(studentid[i]<1)
        {i=100;
  }
        for (int k=0; k<col; k++)
        {
            infile>>score[i][k];
        }
  studentsize++;  
    }
    
    studentsize -=1;
}//end

//find average per quiz
void findqavg(table score, farray avg)
{
 short total=0;
 
 for (int k=0; k<3; k++)
 {
   for(int i=0;i<studentsize; i++)
   {  
   total += score[i][k];

   }
   
  avg[k] = (float)total/(float)studentsize;
  total=0;
  
 }
}//end

//find average per student
void findstudavg(table score, starray studavg)
{
 short total=0;
 
 for (int k=0; k<studentsize; k++)
 {
   for(int i=0;i<col; i++)
   {  
   total += score[k][i];
  
   }
   
  studavg[k] = (float)total/(float)col;
  total=0;
  
 }
}//end

//find lowest grades for each quiz
void findlow(table score, sarray lowest)
{
 
 for (int k=0; k<3; k++)
 {
  for(int i=0;i<studentsize; i++)
  { 
  
   if (score[i][k]<lowest[k])
   {
    lowest[k]=score[i][k];
   }
  
  } 
 } 
}//end

//find highest grades for each quiz
void findhigh(table score, sarray highest)
{
 
 for (int k=0; k<3; k++)
 {
  for(int i=0;i<studentsize; i++)
  { 
  
   if (score[i][k]>highest[k])
   {
    highest[k]=score[i][k];
   }
  
  } 
 } 
}//end

//print out the data in a user friendly manner
void printall(iarray studentid, table score, farray average, 
     starray studavg, sarray highest, sarray lowest, 
     int studentsize)
{
 
 cout<<"Student       Quiz 1       Quiz 2       Quiz 3       Average\n\n";

  
  cout << setiosflags(ios::fixed|ios::showpoint)<<setprecision(2);
  for (int k=0; k<studentsize; k++)
  {
 cout<<studentid[k]<<setw(13)<<score[k][0]<<setw(13)<<score[k][1]<<
    setw(13)<<score[k][2]<<setw(15)<<studavg[k]<<endl; 
  }

  
 cout<<"\n\n\nHigh score "<<setw(7)<<highest[0]<<setw(13)<<highest[1]<<
        setw(13)<<highest[2]<<endl;

 cout<<"\nLow score "<<setw(8)<<lowest[0]<<setw(13)<<lowest[1]<<
          setw(13)<<lowest[2]<<endl;
       
       
 cout<<"\nQuiz average "<<setw(5)<<average[0]<<setw(13)<<average[1]<<
        setw(13)<<average[2];
 
 }//end
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is that when you declare a function like this:

```
void getdata(iarray studentid, ...)
{
    // operations on studentid...
}
```

When you call this function, this actually *copies* the `studentid` variable into the local function scope, instead of changing the original variable. If you want your `getdata` function to modify `studentid`, you will need to pass it by reference (note the &).

```
 void getdata(iarray &studentid, ...)
 {
     // ...
 }
```

This means that your getdata function will operate on a *reference* to studentid, rather than creating a *copy* of studentid, which is deleted when the function ends.

The reason this did not occur with arrays/pointers is that you were effectively passing the memory address to the `getdata` function (as this is what arrays/pointers are). It still copied the variable, but since it was just referring to the memory address, it still updated the data in the same place. Since you are now using the `vector` class, it will copy the data if you don't specify a reference.

Another issue you will likely run into is the way you are inserting data into the vector: you are using `infile >> studentid[i];`, but you don't actually allocate it's size anywhere, so this will likely crash your program. Instead I would recommend either explicitly allocating the vector's size using `studentid.resize()`, or using `push_back`.